# How to extract specific text and some extra characters from a string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, colors, python-re

Let's say I have a text:

```
"background-color:  #ffffe5;\n            color:  #000000;\n        }{\n            background-color:  #ed7215;\n            color: 
#000000; background-color:  #662506;\n            color:  #f1f1f1;"
```

I would like to extract some dictionaries that contain:

```
string1 = {background-color:  #ffffe5}
string2 = {background-color:  #ed7215}
string3 = {background-color:  #662506}
```

The text would normally be longer therefore having several more background colors, is there a way to get all of this. I know this should be done with `re` but I am not sure how to do this with this  `" ".join(string.split())` I know I could use this to remove the unncesary white spaces that would simplify the Issue but still I don´t have any ideas.Any help would be great. or a list with the colors in order would be cool but only the background colors.

Comment: Not sure about the best approach as I don't think the example is sufficient to show the details of the text's structure. Consider splitting on ";"  and finding elements in the resulting list with "background-color" in them. Doesn't look like parsing as json would work given the example

Comment: this seems made for a regex https://regex101.com/r/Y6URU6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

```
import re

text = '''"background-color:  #ffffe5;\n            color:  #000000;\n        }{\n            background-color:  #ed7215;\n            color: #000000; background-color:  #662506;\n            color:  #f1f1f1;"'''

out1 = re.findall('background-color:\s*[^;]+', text)

# OR

out2 = re.findall('background-color:\s*([^;]+)', text)
```

Output:

```
>>> out1
['background-color:  #ffffe5',
 'background-color:  #ed7215',
 'background-color:  #662506']

>>> out2
['#ffffe5', '#ed7215', '#662506']
```